# I want to call a protected overridable sub OnValidatingPassword

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I need to call the Protected Overridable sub OnValidatingPassword from my code behind but I can't because telling me that is protected (which it is)
Is someone to knows how to do it? 
Or from the other hand... did we have the code inside this sub in order to implement it? 
As a new sub of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Protected` methods can only be called from within the class that defines it.  In that way, the `Protected` scope is similar to `Private`.  If you want to call the method from another class, you will need to either change it to `Public`, or wrap it in another `Public` method.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyClassWithProtectedMethod
    Protected Overridable Sub MyProtectedMethod()
        ' ...
    End Sub

    Public Sub MyPublicMethod()
        MyProtectedMethod()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyTestClass
    Public Sub CallProtectedMethod()
        Dim o As New MyClassWithProtectedMethod()
        ' Fails because method "is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected'."
        o.MyProtectedMethod()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CallPublicMethod()
        Dim o As New MyClassWithProtectedMethod()
        ' Works
        o.MyPublicMethod()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The difference, though, between `Private` and `Protected` is that `Protected` members are also accessible to derived classes.  So, if you can't make modifications to the original class, since the method is `Protected`, you'd still be able to make it publicly accessible via a derived class, like this:

```
Public Class MyClassWithProtectedMethod
    Protected Overridable Sub MyProtectedMethod()
        ' ...
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyDerivedClass
    Inherits MyClassWithProtectedMethod

    Public Sub MyPublicMethod()
        MyProtectedMethod()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyTestClass
    Public Sub CallPublicMethod()
        Dim o As New MyDerivedClass()
        ' Works
        o.MyPublicMethod()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Dear Steven... Thank you very much this answer is unique... point it exactly where I want to....